# DDD aggregate root is it correct to have an static method that create the object

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Is it correct to have a Create method like this. Or should I create the User inside a service instead. Does this destroy the DDD concept?

What are best practices for situations like this?

Note: Im using DI too.

```
  public class User : HistoryBase, IAggregateRoot
    {
        private IEnumerable<Role> _roles = new List<Role>();
        public string Name { get; protected set; }
        public string Lastname { get; protected set; }
        public string Email { get; protected set; }
        public string Password { get; protected set; }
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; protected set; }
        public bool Active { get; protected set; }
        public int SiteID { get; protected set; }
        public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get { return _roles; } }

        public static User Create(string name, string lastname, string email, string password, string employeeNumber, Site site)
        {
            var user = new User()
            {
                Name = name,
                Lastname = lastname,
                Email = email,
                Password = password,
                EmployeeNumber = employeeNumber,
                SiteID = site.ID
            };

            return user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you not want to just use a constructor here?

Comment: @MajorRefactoring I have read somewhere that you shouldn't use public constructors for aggregate roots. but i can be wrong.

Comment: I don't recall ever having read that.  There are certainly times when factory methods like the one you've  essentially created here make sense, but I can't really think of reason why using a constructor would be discouraged here.  Can you reference the article that you read that suggested you shouldn't use constructors?

Comment: @MajorRefactoring Possibly referring to this article: http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/ - but that's about a different point though. Aggregates are the result of events and you don't just "create" them. At least not as part of your domain logic. Creating them is an infrastructure concern. And that being an infrastructure concern, also makes the *method* of creating them an infrastructure concern - ergo, it doesn't matter how you do it because it happens outside of the domain logic anyway (I explained this in my answer)

Comment: Yes that was the article

Comment: @MajorRefactoring problem with constructors for me is that i use dapper contrib and it cannot map correctly if i dont have a parameterless constructor. Thansk for help guys

Comment: @Tan Ok, I see. But are you sure that dapper requires that parameterless constructor to be public?  Many ORMs work with private constructors, which means you can leave your API unpolluted, but still have the ORM work correctly.  I haven't worked with Dapper though so I'm not sure.

Comment: @MajorRefactoring Yes im quite sure i tried to create a constructor with a parameter then tried a select query and got errors.

Comment: @Tan Gotcha, but did you try creating an additional, _private_ parameterless constructor?  You can have multiple constructors per class, and those constructors can have different access modifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DDD is mostly about the **naming** of your classes and their properties so that they accurately express the part of the business domain that your software is supposed to represent.

It really doesn't dictate any of the technical implementation details such as how things are instantiated. The point is that the properties and methods on a class have *meaning* in the domain.

A static `.Create()` method doesn't have meaning from the perspective of the domain, but neither does a `new ..()` call to the constructor.

You can make the decision that the method of construction for your domain entities/aggregates shall be `Class.Create()` instead of `new Class()`.

#### It's not "wrong"

If, for example,  the frameworks/libraries you use require a public parameterless default constructor (common with things like EntityFramework and some serialization libraries) and you want your "standard" method of instantiation to be unambiguous (can only be called with all needed parameters), this is a perfectly valid way of accomplishing that.

#### Just be consistent

If you do this, you should do it for all your entities/aggregates. It becomes a convention and it will be documented as a technical implementation detail (just like the constructor is by default).

#### Use CommandHandlers, not services (or factories)

Services are not really for instantiating classes (that's what factories are for).

However, your code seems to hint that you're also applying EventSourcing or some variation thereof. Assuming you're then also doing CQRS, you have `Create` commands ending up in your CommandHandlers `Create` methods. That's where you would place things like validation logic if you need it.

So those CommandHandlers kind of are your factories already, you don't need an additional layer for that.

#### Lastly:

Using static instantiation methods like that is usually for implementing a Fluent API of some sort, for example with the Builder pattern. It offers syntactic sugar for chaining calls.

So it may give other developers / consumers the false impression that the call can be chained (which in your example it cannot).

You'll probably still want to define the default public constructor so you can have a documentation comment to NOT use that one, and have one on `.Create()` that that should be used as the constructor.

All these things considered, is it still better than just using the constructor? Then by all means do it. It doesn't affect the "DDD-ness" as far as I know.

Comment: One of the advantages of using a static factory method is that you could convey that the instantiation might not succeed by returning a nullable or better yet using a try pattern. Receiving a message back if instantiation fails. In my opinion this is better than throwing an exception in the constructor. A constructor isn't transparent/expressive enough to communicate potential failures. And in case of validation that really isn't an exception. As the permutation has already been anticipated.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it correct to have a Create method like this.

In general, that's fine.

It has been noted by Udi Dahan that "create" and "new" aren't usually part of the domain language, so he offered the advice [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/)

> Customers don’t just appear out of thin air.

Which is to say, your domain behaviors should accurately describe how new information is being introduced to the system.

An extra layer of indirection between the constructor and the consuming code can reduce unnecessary coupling - named constructors, factory methods, and builders that return interfaces give you the flexibility to change or decorate the object that you return.  But that's a general modularity / separation of concerns principle, and not at all specific to domain driven design.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something that more clearly states what you are doing instead of `Create`. It looks like you are registering an employee on a website. Try to word it as if someone who will be using the system would say.

If they say, "Hey, will you create this user." Then, your method is fine.

If they say, "Hey, will you register this employee on our website?" Then, you should use:

```
public static Employee RegisterOnWebsite(string name, string lastname, string email, string password, string employeeNumber, Site site)
{
    // Creation Code
}
```

Since you have an employee number as a property. It seems like this user will always be an employee. You should be clear about that and name it as such. Now, your method will read like, `Employee.RegisterOnWebsite(...)`.